# Consolidating Postgres policy

Tags: postgresql, supabase

In a particular table I don't want user to select but can perform insert, update and delete (ignore the use case for now)

Here, Is what I wrote before

```
create policy "workspace_only"
on "public"."services_connected"
as restrictive
for all
to anon
using ((workspace_id = (((current_setting('request.jwt.claims'::text, true))::json ->> 'workspace_id'::text))::bigint));

create policy "no_select"
on "public"."services_connected"
as restrictive
for SELECT
to anon
using (false);
```

but this doesn't allow to insert even when this is true

```
((workspace_id = (((current_setting('request.jwt.claims'::text, true))::json ->> 'workspace_id'::text))::bigint));
```

This works though

```
create policy "no_select"
on "public"."services_connected"
for SELECT
to anon
using (false);

create policy "workspace_insert_only"
on "public"."services_connected"
for insert
to anon
   WITH CHECK ((workspace_id = (((current_setting('request.jwt.claims'::text, true))::json ->> 'workspace_id'::text))::bigint))
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why don't you use REVOKE SELECT ?

Comment: @FrankHeikens I am new to postgres so I don't know about `REVOKE SELECT`. I am using supabase and I saw RLS and hence I decided to it with policy. **2nd** I still do select on table using postgres function `security definer`

Comment: Permissions are done in most (if not all) databases that use SQL, using the statements GRANT and REVOKE. If you want to give a role some permission in a table, you GRANT this role the permission. If you want to revoke a permission, you use REVOKE. Row level security is for individual records in a table. Check chapters 5.7 and 5.8: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html

Comment: @FrankHeikens Thanks for pointing, I tried with REVOKE but then `insert`, `update` and `delete` doesn't work (for whom RLS is applied): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77217951/after-revoking-select-in-postgres-rls-stopped-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the question and clarifying the case: take a look at [Application of Multiple Policies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createpolicy.html#id-1.9.3.75.6.4):

> When multiple policies of the same command type apply to the same command, then **there must be at least one PERMISSIVE policy** granting access to the relation, and all of the RESTRICTIVE policies must pass.

The first one disables all operations regardless of what's `request.jwt.claims` set to because you're missing *at least one `PERMISSIVE` policy*. You can add one as a base and it will work exactly how you expect: [(demo 1)](https://dbfiddle.uk/yeYqeT6_)

```sql
create policy "base_permissive" on "public"."services_connected"
as permissive for all to anon
using (true)
with check (true);
```

The second one works because both policies are by default `permissive` but you'd have to enable `insert` `update` and `delete` separately ([demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/9EmpEOFQ)) to avoid an overlap of a `permissive for all` (or/including `for select`) that would be treated as an alternative to the one that's meant to disable `select` - in that scenario you'd be effectively adding `OR false` that would get ignored ([demo 3](https://dbfiddle.uk/hSffhFT-))

A third way would be to set up one `permissive for all` and one `restrictive for select`: [(demo 4)](https://dbfiddle.uk/GGpKk6w7)

```sql
create policy "no_select" on "public"."services_connected"
as restrictive for SELECT to anon
using (false);

create policy "workspace_insert_only"
on "public"."services_connected"
for all
to anon
using      (workspace_id = ( (current_setting('request.jwt.claims'::text, true)
                             )::json ->> 'workspace_id'::text
                           )::bigint 
           )
with check (workspace_id = ( (current_setting('request.jwt.claims'::text, true)
                             )::json ->> 'workspace_id'::text
                           )::bigint 
           );
```

Note that if you add a `where` section to your `update` or `delete`, or follow `insert`, `update` or `delete` with a `returning` clause, [it'll also be treated as a `select`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html#DDL-PRIV-SELECT) and therefore disabled. Same if it was a `revoke select` preventing that.

---

As to the recommendation, I agree with [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77216775/consolidating-postgres-policy#comment136127882_77216775) that a simple [`REVOKE select ON services_connected FROM anon;`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-revoke.html) will do the job ([demo 5](https://dbfiddle.uk/XKC9TJgr)) and it works fine with `security definer`. You can still guard the `workspace_id` match through RLS policies ([demo 6](https://dbfiddle.uk/aHO3G9uE)).