# After Revoking Select in postgres, RLS stopped working

Tags: postgresql, supabase

I ran this query

`REVOKE SELECT ON services_connected FROM anon;`

and added this policy

```
create policy "workspace_only"
on "public"."services_connected"
for all
to anon
using ((workspace_id = (((current_setting('request.jwt.claims'::text, true))::json ->> 'workspace_id'::text))::bigint));
```

My Expectation was that this would restrict select operation but allow other operations (insert, update, delete) but now I am getting permission denied for all my responses

This is a function I am calling

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public.disconnect_service;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.disconnect_service(service_name_value TEXT)
RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
  workspace_id_value BIGINT := ((current_setting('request.jwt.claims'::text, TRUE))::JSON ->> 'workspace_id')::BIGINT;
BEGIN
  DELETE from services_connected where workspace_id = workspace_id_value and service_name = service_name_value;
  DELETE FROM users_list WHERE workspace_id = workspace_id_value and service_name = service_name_value; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For must `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements you also need `SELECT` privileges. Consider

```
DELETE from services_connected
where workspace_id = workspace_id_value
  and service_name = service_name_value;
```

PostgreSQL first has to *read* the table to identify the rows that meet the `WHERE` condition, only then it can delete the rows. That is not allowed without the `SELECT` privilege, so you get a "permission denied" error. This statement would work:

```
DELETE FROM services_connected;
```

because it has no `WHERE` condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a policy in place that can verify the `workspace_id` condition, you don't need to do it again in the function. You can go one step further and pass the `service_name` as a setting and leave it to the policy to check and compare it the same way you do for `workspace_id`: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/sIrWVlcg)

```
create policy "permissive_base" on "public"."services_connected"
as permissive for all to anon using(true) with check (true);

create policy "workspace_and_sevice_name_match" on "public"."services_connected"
as restrictive for all to anon
using      ((workspace_id = (((current_setting('request.jwt.claims'::text, true))::json ->> 'workspace_id'::text))::bigint)
            AND
            (service_name = (current_setting('request.jwt.claims'::text, true))::json ->> 'service_name'::text )  )
with check ((workspace_id = (((current_setting('request.jwt.claims'::text, true))::json ->> 'workspace_id'::text))::bigint)
            AND
            (service_name = (current_setting('request.jwt.claims'::text, true))::json ->> 'service_name'::text )  );
--same would be required for users_list

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.disconnect_service(service_name_value TEXT)
RETURNS VOID SECURITY INVOKER AS $f$
DELETE from services_connected;
--DELETE FROM users_list;
--for both of these, the RLS attaches 
--`where workspace_id = workspace_id_value and service_name = service_name_value`
$f$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Without the `where`, there's no need for `select` permission. It's breaking these statement the same way a `returning` clause would - both of them potentially leak the contents of the table `anon` shouldn't be able to inspect, so

That, or define the function with [`security definer`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#id-1.9.3.67.6) parameter the way you did for a selector function [you mentioned in the other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77216775/consolidating-postgres-policy/77218056#comment136128337_77216775).

Comment: `(service_name = (current_setting('request.jwt.claims'::text, true))::json ->> 'service_name'::text )  )`  -> `request.jwt.claims` won't have service_name

Comment: I have zero knowledge of what's actually in that setting beyond `service_id`, based on what you presented in your questions. The idea is that if you want to revoke the `select` permission, you'd need to pass the service name in a custom setting (either separate or part of that JSON) checked by an RLS policy, or to define the function with the `security definer` parameter, as a user that does have the adequate permissions.

Comment: Yap, this is helpful.